# How useful is Android Wear without Google Apps?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, rom-flashing, android-wear

I'm thinking about flashing my phone to Cyanogenmod, but I have an Moto 360, so I'm wondering how much of Android Wear is still functioning without Gapps. Does anyone have experiences with this?

I don't really mind things like Google Maps not working properly, but I would like Google Search to work (at at least basic task). I also wouldn't mind installing just the Android Wear app.

Comment: ...I thought you can't pair Android Wear without GAPPS? That's what I've experienced. I got a G Watch by the way, which is now abandoned...

Answer (score 0):

When flashing cyanogenmod you can also flash [GAPPS](http://opengapps.org/). But without it your watch will pretty useless. You won't have maps, hangouts, agenda, Google, Keep, Play Music, Reminders, etc. So I would **HIGHLY** recommend flashing GAPPS along with CyanogenMod.